# CanvasJs, update data

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, canvasjs

I want to show some data in an Chart. The size is around 200k datapoints x16 - which is the stacked value. I hope that this library is able to render these data in time.

The Array looks like: [16][250000], where the outer Array is the stacked value and the Inner holds the data. [n][m] = {x: 1...250000, y: 0...1}. If I have [1][7000] = {x: 7000, y: data} or [12][7000]={7000, y:otherData} -> this will be stacked.

The data will be loaded only after an User Interaction.

My problem is now that I am not able to fill the graph with data. I have seen http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/ .

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dataPoints = []; //or: dataPoints ={};
    window.onload = function () {
        chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart",
                {
                    title: {
                        text: "asdf"
                    },
                    data: [{
                        type: "stackedColumn",
                        dataPoints: dataPoints
                    }]
                });

        chart.render();
    }
  function update(data) {
        //or:  dataPoints=[[],[]];
        var size= data[0].length;
        var outer= data.length;
        for (i= 0; i< outer; i++) {
            for (j= 0; j< size; j++) {                   
               dataPoints[i][j].push({y: data[i][j].y}); //here is the error
               console.log( data[i][j].y);
            }

        }
     chart.render();
    }
```

No matter how I do it, I will get an "*cannot set property of x/y/0 of "undefined"*".

I knew it has to do with the Array initialisation and already have tried various ways but I do not get how to init it correctly to later fill the data (and I do not know how much data will come). Once it has it´s problems already at (0,0) and then when it "goes to (1,0).

**2nd)** Could someone give me an recommendation how I can reduce the loaded data? Because if I make some tests it´s extremely slow and it´s possible that there will be 1.000.000 x 16 data points later (as seen http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/range-changing/ , crashes at >2.000.000). Especially with Interaction like synchronizing, zooming and panning.

Answer (score 2):

data should contain array of dataSeries which should be in form of object.
This dataSeries should contain dataPoints which should again be in the form of object.

```
var myData = [];
function update() {
    var size= data[0].length;
    var outer= data.length;
    for (i= 0; i< outer; i++) {
        var dataSeries = [];
        for (j= 0; j< size; j++) {
            dataSeries.push({y: data[i][j]});
        }
        myData.push({type: "stackedColumn", dataPoints: dataSeries});
    }
    chart.render();
}
```

Replace this line

```
data: [{
    type: "stackedColumn",
    dataPoints: dataPoints
}]
```

with this

```
data: myData
```

And call update() function once the user interacts.